# Running caffe gives error Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (30 vs. 0) unknown error

Tags: drivers, nvidia, c++, cuda, opencv

I'm trying to get caffe to run such that I can use it via python. To do this I have followed [this](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) tutorial. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

When I get to `make runtest` I get the error :

```
$ make runtest
CXX/LD -o .build_release/test/test_all.testbin src/caffe/test/test_caffe_main.cpp
.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_memory_data_layer.o: In function `caffe::MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_Test<caffe::CPUDevice<float> >::TestBody()':
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x333): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x3f5): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x407): undefined reference to `cv::randu(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_memory_data_layer.o: In function `caffe::MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_Test<caffe::GPUDevice<float> >::TestBody()':
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x333): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x3f5): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x407): undefined reference to `cv::randu(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_memory_data_layer.o: In function `caffe::MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_Test<caffe::CPUDevice<float> >::TestBody()':
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x340): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x407): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x418): undefined reference to `cv::randu(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0xcc0): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0xd82): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0xd93): undefined reference to `cv::randu(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_memory_data_layer.o: In function `caffe::MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_Test<caffe::GPUDevice<float> >::TestBody()':
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x341): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x408): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x41a): undefined reference to `cv::randu(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0xcd5): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0xd97): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0xda9): undefined reference to `cv::randu(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_memory_data_layer.o: In function `caffe::MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_Test<caffe::CPUDevice<double> >::TestBody()':
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x333): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x3f5): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x407): undefined reference to `cv::randu(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_memory_data_layer.o: In function `caffe::MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_Test<caffe::GPUDevice<double> >::TestBody()':
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x333): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x3f5): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe53MemoryDataLayerTest_AddMatVectorDefaultTransform_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x407): undefined reference to `cv::randu(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_memory_data_layer.o: In function `caffe::MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_Test<caffe::CPUDevice<double> >::TestBody()':
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x386): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x44d): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x45e): undefined reference to `cv::randu(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0xd20): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0xde2): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0xdf3): undefined reference to `cv::randu(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_memory_data_layer.o: In function `caffe::MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_Test<caffe::GPUDevice<double> >::TestBody()':
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x340): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x407): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x418): undefined reference to `cv::randu(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0xcc0): undefined reference to `vtable for cv::_InputArray'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0xd82): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_memory_data_layer.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe41MemoryDataLayerTest_TestSetBatchSize_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0xd93): undefined reference to `cv::randu(cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_io.o: In function `caffe::ReadImageToDatumReference(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, int, int, bool, caffe::Datum*)':
test_io.cpp:(.text+0x1d9): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
test_io.cpp:(.text+0x216): undefined reference to `cv::_OutputArray::_OutputArray(cv::Mat&)'
test_io.cpp:(.text+0x228): undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:597: recipe for target '.build_release/test/test_all.testbin' failed
make: *** [.build_release/test/test_all.testbin] Error 1
```

and when I use the cmake runtest I get the error

```
$ make runtest
[  1%] Built target proto
[ 68%] Built target caffe
[ 70%] Built target gtest
[100%] Built target test.testbin
Cuda number of devices: 0
Current device id: 0
Current device name: 
Note: Randomizing tests' orders with a seed of 56045 .
[==========] Running 2021 tests from 267 test cases.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 3 tests from ThresholdLayerTest/1, where TypeParam = caffe::CPUDevice<double>
[ RUN      ] ThresholdLayerTest/1.TestSetup
E1017 10:41:43.387125 23233 common.cpp:113] Cannot create Cublas handle. Cublas won't be available.
E1017 10:41:43.399794 23233 common.cpp:120] Cannot create Curand generator. Curand won't be available.
E1017 10:41:43.399904 23233 common.cpp:140] Curand not available. Skipping setting the curand seed.
[       OK ] ThresholdLayerTest/1.TestSetup (26 ms)
[ RUN      ] ThresholdLayerTest/1.Test
[       OK ] ThresholdLayerTest/1.Test (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] ThresholdLayerTest/1.Test2
[       OK ] ThresholdLayerTest/1.Test2 (0 ms)
[----------] 3 tests from ThresholdLayerTest/1 (26 ms total)

[----------] 2 tests from EuclideanLossLayerTest/2, where TypeParam = caffe::GPUDevice<float>
[ RUN      ] EuclideanLossLayerTest/2.TestGradient
F1017 10:41:43.400226 23233 syncedmem.hpp:18] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (30 vs. 0)  unknown error
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f6dcb6975cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7f6dcb699433  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7f6dcb69715b  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7f6dcb699e1e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7f6dcc40dae1  caffe::SyncedMemory::mutable_cpu_data()
    @     0x7f6dcc409cb1  caffe::Blob<>::Reshape()
    @     0x7f6dcc40a17f  caffe::Blob<>::Reshape()
    @     0x7f6dcc40a22c  caffe::Blob<>::Blob()
    @           0xa8e45e  caffe::EuclideanLossLayerTest<>::EuclideanLossLayerTest()
    @           0xa8e7db  testing::internal::TestFactoryImpl<>::CreateTest()
    @           0xd856b3  testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0xd7e533  testing::TestInfo::Run()
    @           0xd7e6c5  testing::TestCase::Run()
    @           0xd8025f  testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
    @           0xd80583  testing::UnitTest::Run()
    @           0x86e16d  main
    @     0x7f6dc3905830  __libc_start_main
    @           0x872b39  _start
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest' failed
make[3]: *** [src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest] Error 134
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:328: recipe for target 'src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:335: recipe for target 'src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:240: recipe for target 'runtest' failed
make: *** [runtest] Error 2
```

the first error suggests that maybe something is wrong with opencv but when I do python import cv2 that no error is shown.

I'm trying to use it to run (and later change) the code at https://github.com/fzliu/style-transfer which when I try to run it gives me the error

```
/style-transfer$ python style.py -s /home/thijs/workspace/style-transfer/images/content/johannesburg.jpg -c /home/thijs/workspace/style-transfer/images/content/nanjing.jpg
style.py:main:13:22:16.988 -- Starting style transfer.
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F1017 13:22:17.016680 28527 common.cpp:151] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (30 vs. 0)  unknown error
*** Check failure stack trace:
```

I have an NVIDIA Quadro K1000M with the nvidia binary driver version 340.96. Elsewere it was suggested to try `sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe` but that didn't resolve the problem. The error message associated with error code 30 is
     /**
     * This indicates that an unknown internal error has occurred.
     */
    cudaErrorUnknown                      =     30,

I'm running the following cudas version

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

Edit as described in the comments I looked at the driver/cuda versions and updated my drivers to a new version. I now get the error

```
F1024 14:48:14.636173 23574 syncedmem.hpp:18] Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (11 vs. 0)  invalid argument
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7fdbb836e5cd  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7fdbb8370433  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7fdbb836e15b  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7fdbb8370e1e  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7fdbb90e4ae1  caffe::SyncedMemory::mutable_cpu_data()
    @     0x7fdbb90df631  caffe::Blob<>::Reshape()
    @     0x7fdbb90dfaff  caffe::Blob<>::Reshape()
    @     0x7fdbb90dfbac  caffe::Blob<>::Blob()
    @           0xb98c3c  caffe::NeuronLayerTest<>::NeuronLayerTest()
    @           0xb9965b  testing::internal::TestFactoryImpl<>::CreateTest()
    @           0xd856b3  testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0xd7e533  testing::TestInfo::Run()
    @           0xd7e6c5  testing::TestCase::Run()
    @           0xd8025f  testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
    @           0xd80583  testing::UnitTest::Run()
    @           0x86e16d  main
    @     0x7fdbb05dc830  __libc_start_main
    @           0x872b39  _start
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest' failed
make[3]: *** [src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest] Error 134
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:328: recipe for target 'src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:335: recipe for target 'src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:240: recipe for target 'runtest' failed
make: *** [runtest] Error 2
```

anybody know what could cause that one?

Comment: it doesn't look like it can see your cuda device

Comment: @Amias That might be part of the problem any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks for @veranedi([link](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16280/how-do-i-message-another-user-here))  to point out that my cuda version may be to new and that I should retry with cuda version 6.5. Now to find a version of cuda that will install on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Gonna gives [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/6.5.14-2) a try.

Comment: That question seems to resolve the problem (I have another problem now but I will give that it's own question).

Comment: great ! please could you update the question to include the fix so others can benefit from it easily ?

Comment: @Amias yes I'm going to give veranedi until the end of the bounty grace period to properly post the answer so (s)he can still receive it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it turns out that you need to have the proper version of the nvidia drivers to go with the cuda version. 
In this case the problem was caused by having older drivers and updating the drivers to version 361 over 340 caused this problem to go away. Alternatively I could probably have downgraded cuda to version 6.5.

credit to veranedi for suggesting this.