# __GI___pthread_mutex_lock error in opencv/caffe

Tags: 16.04, compiling, cuda, opencv, caffe

Having resolved the problem in my [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838289/running-caffe-gives-error-check-failed-error-cudasuccess-30-vs-0-unknown)

I installed caffe following the [guide](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) and it works fine until I get to the `make runtest` step.

At this point it throws the

```
[ RUN      ] ImageDataLayerTest/0.TestResize
*** Aborted at 1477424981 (unix time) try "date -d @1477424981" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @     0x7efe83917d84 __GI___pthread_mutex_lock
*** SIGSEGV (@0x3038) received by PID 8354 (TID 0x7efe8c938180) from PID 12344; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7efe8391f3d0 (unknown)
    @     0x7efe83917d84 __GI___pthread_mutex_lock
    @     0x7efe61f51008 (unknown)
    @     0x7efe62005671 (unknown)
    @     0x7efe620057e5 (unknown)
    @     0x7efe61f56cb4 (unknown)
    @     0x7efe61f584e7 (unknown)
    @     0x7efe61f2bc66 (unknown)
    @     0x7efe61e2af3d (unknown)
    @     0x7efe61e2aed8 (unknown)
    @     0x7efe627b3d30 (unknown)
    @     0x7efe627b4233 clGetPlatformIDs
    @     0x7efe86f78ad5 (anonymous namespace)::opencl_fn3<>::switch_fn()
    @     0x7efe8702786a cv::ocl::haveOpenCL()
    @     0x7efe87036c08 cv::ocl::useOpenCL()
    @     0x7efe8561af7c cv::resize()
    @     0x7efe8431dbe7 caffe::ReadImageToCVMat()
    @     0x7efe842dbe7e caffe::ImageDataLayer<>::DataLayerSetUp()
    @     0x7efe8422e1e3 caffe::BasePrefetchingDataLayer<>::LayerSetUp()
    @           0x48c95f caffe::Layer<>::SetUp()
    @           0x4a8597 caffe::ImageDataLayerTest_TestResize_Test<>::TestBody()
    @           0x8e0693 testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<>()
    @           0x8d9caa testing::Test::Run()
    @           0x8d9df8 testing::TestInfo::Run()
    @           0x8d9ed5 testing::TestCase::Run()
    @           0x8db1af testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests()
    @           0x8db4d3 testing::UnitTest::Run()
    @           0x466e7d main
    @     0x7efe83565830 __libc_start_main
    @           0x46e489 _start
    @                0x0 (unknown)
```

error.

here is some relevant information: 
nvcc version:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

graphics card:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK107GLM [Quadro K1000M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:35 memory:d8000000-d8ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:d9080000-d90fffff
```

my graphics driver is

```
nvidia-opencl-icd-361-updates
```

I googled for the problem but could only find a suggestion that it may be a problem with opencv (I use `opencv-3.1.0` ).

Comment: I'm doubting if this will do better on super user or stackoverflow so feel free to migrate if a mod things it will do better there.

Comment: user @Aaron3468 suggested in the c++ stackoverflow launch that this might be related to a bug in the [gnome shell](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1281302). Any idea how to check if that's it? (edit wait that's the gnome shell which I'm not supposed to be using)

Comment: is your system upgraded?

Comment: @MarkYisri it has recently run apt-get update/upgrade but according to one the deeper logs the kernal version may be out of date (now looking on how to fix this)